# SetRobots in Magento for a CMS-Page - how?

Tags: magento, magento-1.7

I want to set the meta-robots-tag in magento 1.7.02 of my homepage (which is defined via a cms-page) to index,follow.

I try to do that by this code that's set in the tabe Page Layout (XML for Page Layout):

```
<reference name="head">
   <action method="setRobots"><value>INDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
</reference>
```

But the meta-tag doesn't get updated (it's no cache-problem ;) )Where could I look else to change this tag?

My template is using this code to define robots:

```
<meta name="robots" content="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($this->getRobots()) ?>
```

Answer (score 1):

I was able to update the robots meta tag using your layout update exactly as described. I would double check that the CMS page you are expecting is the one actually being used, as well as the templates (insert debugging output). However, another way you can do the same thing is editing or creating the `local.xml` file in your theme’s `layout` subdirectory:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<layout version="0.1.0">
    <cms_index_index>
        <reference name="head">
            <action method="setRobots"><value>INDEX,FOLLOW</value></action>
        </reference>
    </cms_index_index>
</layout>
```

If that still doesn’t work, you have a pretty good idea that something is interfering in your theme/templates.

Comment: Thanks. That didn't work also. Where was a good starting point to check what is interfering into my template?

Comment: @Daiaiai - One thing you could try is setting a different value on the block like `<action method="setRobotsDebug"><value>foobar</value></action>` and then in the template output the value: `echo $this->getRobotsDebug()`. There are probably too many possibilities for me to be able to walk you through debugging everything. The goal is to just make sure all your assumptions about which code is being executed are true (i.e. correct CMS page, theme, page layout + templates, etc).